# Is Db access from my Services Layer a bad thing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository-pattern

My last app implemented UoW, DI, IoC, Repository Pattern, Factories, all sorts of stuff that seemed neat, but made maintenance and debugging a pain.

I'm taking the opposite approach with my most recent app - no DI, no IoC, no UoW, just MVC, Services Layer, and DB.  I'm probably thinking about Repository Pattern all wrong, but the reading that I've done suggests that it's responsible only for Db access, and not Business logic, to keep the two concerns separated.

In implementing a repository pattern, I feel like I'm just duplicating so much of my Service layer.  For example, in my UserService class, I have the following:

```
    public void UpdateAboutMe(AboutMeDto request)
    {
        using (var db = CreateContext())
        {
            var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Username.Equals(request.Username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
            if (user != null)
            {
                user.AboutMe = request.AboutMe;
                SaveChanges(db);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("Null User");
            }
        }
    }
```

This way, the Service grabs the object, updates a single field, and commits the changes to the DB, and disposes the context.

In my UserService, I have other methods like this:

- GetUserByUserName
- GetUserById
- GetUsersWithChildEntities
- GetUsersWithoutChildEntities (faster than the former, right?)
- UpdateUserThumbnail
- UpdateUserBio
- UpdateUserInterests

Wouldn't every one of these need a corresponding Repo method?

If I implement a repository method, the above service might look like this:

```
public void UpdateAboutMe(AboutMeDto request)
        {
            return _userRepository.UpdateAboutMe(request);
        }
```

Which seems cleaner, but not a *lot* cleaner since I'm just moving stuff around - and if I decide to change my one of my Get methods to include some child entity, I now have to create another method in the Repo, update the Interface, and update the Service method, instead of just doing it directly from my service method.

I'm basically interested in learning whether or not I should implement Repository Pattern, based on the limited understanding I've demonstrated above.  It seems like it's either add a vertical layer of complexity to your app, or just make your service layer a little beefier.

IMO - with EF lazy loading and per-field updates - Repository Pattern seems like so much more overhead.

And, I'm not huge on TDD in this case, so I'd like to keep testability out of the equation if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patterns exist to solve problems.  If the way the pattern solves the problem introduces others that aren't acceptable in your environment, then either you are doing it wrong or you just need to go down a different path.

Along with this, just because something is a pattern doesn't mean you should blindly use it.  There are many "patterns" that I consider to be pure garbage due to introducing large swaths of code for relatively little gain.

I'm not sure why you have a method call to update a single field on a single record.  That seems to make things a bit difficult and certainly can cause lots of DB queries to fire off when just one would do, essentially undermining performance for no gain.

Two examples:

```
GetUser(String userName, Int32 id, Boolean withEntities);
```

or

```
GetUser(String userName, Boolean withEntities);
GetUser(Int32 id, Boolean withEntities);
```

The first one combines your common ways of acquiring a specific user account.  The second one duplicates code, but splits it out.  Later you might decide to add a `GetUser(String email, Boolean withEntities)` at some point.

The various `UpdateUser...` methods you have I'd roll into one.  Passing a full User object into it and letting the one method update the entire thing.  There are very very few circumstances where I'd have methods update just a single field.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I have some questions:  " lots of DB queries to fire off when just one would do, " - My client application sends a request to an API controller containing only ID and AboutMe (to keep the payload minimal) - API controller calls a corresponding service method so that I'm not re-assigning fields that don't need to be re-assigned.  I don't see how this could generate unnecessary db calls - the field-limitation is intentional.  Thoughts?

Comment: So, someone is on their own User edit page.  They decide to change their name, birth date and about me.  What happens .. are 3 DB calls made?  If so, then the API is wrong.  This site is a good example, go edit your profile.  You'll see 7 potential fields to make a change on.  I guarantee SO isn't issuing 7 db calls when someone clicks save.

Comment: It's not a form - It's assumed that they only update one field at a time - there is no "save all of these at the same time".

Comment: What's the normal usage? Are they tabbing through and making changes?  Maybe I don't understand the layout because I can't see this being a good thing.

Comment: normal usage is in-line, AJAX, per-field updates.  This is getting into UX though :p

Comment: Without knowing much else about the app, I think that model would die under any level of usage.  Think about it in terms of the number of simultaneous users of your app.  If you issue a separate query when they are making a change, tab, make a change, etc.. then multiply that by your user base you will likely need to scale out your hardware.  This isn't so much a UX discussion as it is an overall design one.  That said, I realize that I only have 2 minor bits of information so I could be off base.

Comment: getting back on topic: if that is the way the design says to go then your user service and userrepository are going to end up with one method per field that you allow to be updatable in your database and there isn't much you can do about it except copy/paste a metric ton of code.  At which point you better be using a pattern that allows you to easily scale out across multiple machines.  I'd probably drop the Repository pattern and move to having the service hit the DB direct.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't interested in TDD, IoC/DI, or reuseability, there's no need to have excess layers.  Each layer has a purpose, but if you do not have that purpose you do not need that layer.

However, it will become more difficult to rewrite things once people start dying during a server outage.